# How to add JSON5 schemas in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, json5

I am trying to configure JSON5 schemas in my settings.json file in VS Code, [to have intellisense]

I would like to do something similar to what is available today for JSON editing https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_mapping-in-the-user-settings, something like the below

```
"json5.schemas": [
    {
        "fileMatch": [
            "*test.json5"
        ],
        "url": "https://example.com/json-schemas/example.json5"
    }
]
```

Could you please help me achieve this (by any means within VSCode)?

Motivation: Please note as of this post, IntelliJ IDEA supports JSON5 https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/json.html#ws_json_choose_version

Comment: VSCode doesn't support JSON5 and the only JSON5 extension I've found only does syntax highlighting, so there's no way to do this currently.